# Unable to freeze the header pane using axlsx with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, axlsx

I am Using the Axlsx gem with rails to create the Excel sheet. I need the header to be fixed and frozen. The header to should be always visible even we scroll down.
rails version 3.2.1
gem 'axlsx'

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 8):

You can freeze the pane like this example:

```
  require 'axlsx'
  XLSX_temp = 'simple.xlsx'

  Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
      p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => 'DATA') do |sheet|
        sheet.add_row(%w{key col1 col2 col3 col4 col5})
        #Fix first line and column
        sheet.sheet_view.pane do |pane|
          pane.top_left_cell = "B2"
          pane.state = :frozen_split
          pane.y_split = 1
          pane.x_split = 1
          pane.active_pane = :bottom_right
        end

        10.times{
          sheet.add_row(%w{1 2 3 4 5 6})
        }
      end    

      puts "Write %s" % XLSX_temp
      p.serialize(XLSX_temp)
  end
```

The result has a fixed first column and row:

[image]

With `pane.x_split = 0` only the first row is fixed.

Comment: Can we freeze some rows whose starting row is other than the first row?
 Your code will freeze the first rows BUT I want something like, to freeze 4 rows starting from row 3 i.e. rows 3,4,5 & 6.

Comment: Is this possible inside Excel?  I can't check it actual myself, but I think excel allows only to fix rows from top.

Comment: Yes it is allowed in Excel. Google spreadsheet have that feature and I think MS office have that too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the axlsx examples page here:

https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb#L575-L581

````
# Repeat printing of header rows.
#```ruby
if examples.include? :repeated_header
  wb.add_worksheet(:name => "repeated header") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row %w(These Column Header Will Render On Every Printed Sheet)
    200.times { sheet.add_row %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) }
    wb.add_defined_name("'repeated header'!$1:$1", :local_sheet_id => sheet.index, :name => '_xlnm.Print_Titles')
  end
end
````